# How can I broadcast data to multiple SPI slaves and how it works?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, spi

I know basic SPI protocol and its master to slave operations. I want to know that is it possible to broadcast data on multiple slave? If it is possible then how it works.

I've heard that after writing to any SPI slave you have to read from slave even if you are not going to use read data. How is this possible in case broadcast if broadcast is possible?

Comment: "I've heard that after writing to any SPI slave you have to read from slave even if you are not going to use read data."  To begin with, do you know how SPI works? It does not "read" or "write" but _transceives_ data at full duplex.

Comment: I don't know. I am trying to know. That is why So is for. Right? If you don't know or can not explain then go home man. Let other answer.

Comment: This question was asked in college viva and I was told that it is possible. I just needed to explain how it works.  MISO and MOSI lines of slave are connected togather with Master. Now can you tell me the answer or any documents which explain this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Since SPI is 4- wire interface. The SS line is used for slave selection.One SPI master can have multiple slaves but it cannot select all the slaves at once since it is either using some bit or SS signal to select the slave(and cannot select multiple slave at a single time).

SPI works in full duplex mode(most of time and cases), and is implemented using shift registers. Hence while writing the data on MOSI(assumption: master is writing),we are getting the data in MISO line too (inserting data in master shift register does shift the data in slave shift register). Hence we get data on both of the TX and RX lines.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you have multiple SPI controllers. I have four SPI controllers connected to four different chips of the same type. I control the SS in software because the the SPI controller can't control it in a useful way. My driver has read, write, and broadcast methods. Read and write act on one SPI controller instance while the broadcast method (write-only of course) takes an array of SPI controller instances.

The broadcast method then takes the common address buffer of size bytes and the common data buffer of size bytes and sends them to all four SPI controllers sequentially (but close in time) to effect a broadcast from the caller's perspective. It isn't a hardware based broadcast but it does allow higher level software to think it is broadcasting common commands and setup data to all four chips at once.

It is also overall more time-efficient than sequentially sending the same thing to all four chips since efficiencies are to be had by having the lower layer SPI controller do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use simplex SPI with one master and many slaves, you can create an interface of 1 to many.  Assuming DMA, you posit the size of the transaction and a data buffer. The physical interface is 2 wire plus ground - CLK and MOSI. NSS is software selected not hardware.  In theory you DMA from the master and the slaves get the data.  This is a one way channel.  I have been playing around with these sorts of configurations and this one seems to be working. Hardware is STM32f0/g0 architecture.  I am also looking into ring topologies.. which were fun it the 90s, and may still be fun..

Answer (score -4):

You cannot broadcast data to multiple slaves at the same time.

Comment: SPI does not defined higher layers. There very well are ways to connect the hardware such that one can send data to multiple slaves.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: This is not the place to tutor and apparently too broad. Just read the specs of typical MCU SPI-peripherals and get creative.

Comment: I have not seen any MCU which can broadcast to multiple slaves at the same time (Not many though). I think it is good if you can provide some reading material which can support your claims.

Comment: All MCUs can do! It depends solely on the slaves, resp. the interconnections of SS and MISO

Comment: Given that the MISO lines aren't used or connected to each other, there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to broadcast. To read something back from all slaves, well that's another story entirely.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no reason not to have to MISO lines connected. One just must ensure they don't interfere for for broadcasts. One variant could be to use a mux or use different MCU pins (many MCUs provide the same signal at multiple pins). As I wrote: there are ways.

Comment: Or it might work to put a series resistor from each MISO output to the single MISO input, so when multiple slaves are selected the MISO outputs don't fight each other too much?