# Using Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) to talk to several slaves simultaneously

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, uart, spi, atmega

I have four Atmega328p in a single board and I want one of them send the same data (i.e. sensor readings) to the other three simultaneously. I'm not interested in a bidirectional communication. I read this thread ([How can I broadcast data to multiple SPI slaves and how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701098/)) about SPI broadcasting, and someone mentioned not being possible because in SPI communication is full duplex and MISO and MOSI lines are active at the same time. However, I was wondering if I could just let the MISO lines unconnected and all SS pins pulled low, so I could broadcast a message to all slaves simultaneosly, taking into account that I do not need any type of response from the slaves to the master.

So, is this possible? Or how else could I work around this problem? I was also considering on using UART's Tx line and connect all the receivers in parallel to it, but I'm not sure that would work too.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Yes, it is!  Connect all SS lines together as you will be controlling all simultaneously.  So, the same SCLK, MOSI, and SS lines go to all chips.  Leave MISO floating (or better, pulled up).

Comment: Using the uart would also work. You don’t need RS485 if you do as you describe and wire the master TC to all the slave RX (but obviously it’s master->slave communication only)

Comment: Typo Master TC->Master TX